# Safe wrapping for fiberglass around pipes?

Tags: water, insulation, heating, materials

If I wrap pipes with fiberglass for insulation but I'm worried about the health risks of exposed fiberglass, is there something that I could wrap around the fiberglass? If so, what and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and much easier. Specially made foam insulation for pipes is readily available in many diameters and literally just snaps over the pipes via a slit in the tube.  Then there is plastic covering glue that you pull off once you have the insulation over the pipe.  Pull the plastic, squeeze it together and wa la you have an insulated pipe. I posted an image for 1/2" pipe, but it's available in many sizes.

[image: Pipe insulation foam]

Comment: Thanks @George Anderson! Are you saying that this is recommended wrapped around fiberglass, used as a substitute, or both?

Comment: As a substitute.  You don't need both.  I think these also come in a couple of thicknesses so if you are in a really really cold climate you might want to find the thicker versions.

Comment: the glue holds the foam together but not to the pipe so you can install a section of foam, shove it up into an inaccessible  area, install another section of  foam and so on.... until you hit a pipe clamp +1

Comment: Would your recommendations change if I were insulating around a pipe wrapped with heating cable? If so, how?

Comment: First read the instructions for the heating cable